# Complex manipulation of Pandas data frame to perform plotting and statistical analysis with Python

Tags: python, pandas

I am reading a CSV file with Python via Pandas and creating a data frame. Here is a portion of the print statement showing hourly data:

```
      Location                Time         Count      Speed    Parameter1...
0         CCNY 2010-01-01 06:00:00             1      48.00    35.8
1         CCNY 2010-01-01 07:00:00             2      18.00    32.6
...        ...                 ...           ...        ...    ...
97775     PS19 2013-12-31 21:00:00           178       9.27    12.8
97776     PS19 2013-12-31 22:00:00           190       8.90    11.7
```

(The time is one column holding both date and time.)

This is what I need to do:

- Plot Speed vs. various parameters for each Location on a daily basis (the data holds hourly information). I didn't show the various parameters on the print example above but they are held in other columns for each row. For each CCNY location, there is speed and 4 other parameters. For the PS19 location there is only speed and 1 other parameter. So, for the month of January there will be 31 plots for CCNY for Speed vs Parameter1, 31 plots for CCNY for Speed vs Parameter2, 31 plots for CCNY for Speed vs Parameter3, and 31 plots for CCNY for speed vs Parameter4. For the other location of PS19 there will be only 31 plots of speed vs a Parameter1. Please comment if this is confusing!
- Next, for each plot I need to add a best fit line and calculate the slope and r-squared value.

Given all the large output, I would like to output all plots as images to a folder and the slope and r squared value for each Location and day to CSV.

I am creating the data frame as follows:

```
def parse_date(raw_date):
    return datetime.strptime(raw_date, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

df = pd.read_csv('part-00000', delimiter=',')
df['Time'] = df['Time'].map(parse_date)
```

This is my attempt so far, but it does not function correctly:

```
locations = { 'CCNY': ('Parameter1', 'Parameter2', 'Parameter3', 'Parameter4'),
             'PS19': ('Parameter1') }

for location in locations.keys():
    for i in xrange(0, len(locations[location])):  
        df.groupby(df['Time'].dt.day).plot(x='Average_Speed', y=locations[location][i], style = 'o', title=location+": "+locations[location][i]+" "+str(i))
        plt.savefig('plots/plot'+str(location)+str(locations[location][i])+'_'+str(i)+'.png')
```

Comment: Could you be more specific about how it isn't functioning correctly?

Comment: @Jody: the output as of now is 4 plots for the CCNY location, one for each parameter... it should be 31 plots times 4 (one set of 31 plots for each parameter) as so: day one will have 4 plots of CCNY:Speed vs Parameter1, CCNY:Speed vs Parameter2, CCNY:Speed vs Parameter3, and CCNY:Speed vs Parameter4... day two will have 4 plots of the same but for the second day, and so forth until we get to the end of the month of January for 31 plots times 4. Then this process will continue for the rest of the months in the file...

Comment: @Jody: the file has 3 years of data, but i was trying to lay out my example for one month, so that's why I say 31 plots

Comment: It's because you're not changing the filename based on 'parameter'.  So you keep overwriting the 4 files....31 times.  You might want to try stepping through your code before posting here.  Pycharm has a nice community edition that works well...even with iPython Notebook if that's what you're using.

Comment: @Jody: I appreciate your help. I still don't see it. I'm going to update my attempt now in the problem statement to loop through all locations. It still doesn't work. I'm using Sublime Text 2.

Comment: @Jody: I see how the loop would not work and I think that's what you are getting to... and that is the issue, I'm not exactly sure how to build the loop.

Comment: If you haven't done it already, I recommend breaking out a smaller chunk of your data and making sure the groupby.plot step is behaving the way you expect, before adding the additional looping. Also, are you sure the dataset has a full set of values for every day? I did something like this recently, and ended up using generators for each separate step.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem:

First, need to loop through the groups created by the groupby and this why it was only producing 4 plots:

```
for i, group in df.groupby(df['Time'].dt.date)
```

Second, to calculate slope and r-value it was possible to use SciPy:

```
from scipy.stats import linregress
```

And add this within the loop:

```
slope, intercept, r, p, stderr = linregress(group['Speed'], group[Parameter])
```